# "invalid bearer token received" when using newly requested bearer token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I'm using Postman, first I'm requesting a token:

> https://my-internal-test-site/identity/connect/token

That provides me with a correct token response:

```
{
    "access_token": "MY_BEARER_TOKEN",
    "expires_in": ?,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "MY_REFRESH_TOKEN"
}
```

Than I POST to the actual url I need:

> https://my-internal-test-site/api/start-stuff

Using this value for the Authorization header:

```
BEARER *MY_BEARER_TOKEN*
```

Although that's a newly requested token, I get:

```
{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

When I check my API log, I see this:

```
Error | IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IntrospectionEndpointTokenProvider | Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request.

Warn | Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware | invalid bearer token received
```

Which is weird, because it's a new token I'm using. Maybe something else is going wrong that causes this, but if so it's not described here, nor in the Identity Server log. Which seems just fine:

```
Info | IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator | Creating token response
Info | IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator | Processing token request
Info | Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventService | Information - 2020 - Refresh token issued -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.RefreshTokenDetails
Info | Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventService | Information - 2000 - Access token issued -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.AccessTokenIssuedDetails
Info | Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventService | Success - 3000 - Endpoint success -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.EndpointDetail
Info | IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController | End token request
Info | IdentityServer3.Core.Results.TokenResult | Returning token response.
```

> Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Please show us an example of a token (a real value - don't make one up) that isn't working.

Comment: Got this same problem and didn't find solution to it yet. I get 401 back from api and NLog shows: Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware|invalid bearer token received.

Token I generate is a JWT Bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

Figures, the error I got wasn't the error that was happening:

> An underlying api url wasn't publicly accessible

That's why it worked locally but not on the test server, because then I'm using that public url. It's weird that none of this showed up in any of the logs but what can you do ...

> I checked with the sys admins and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same error messages on localhost, but test server worked fine.

It turned out to be a problem with the use of a self signed SSL certificate i started using a few months ago.
The default IIS express development certificate worked fine, but my selfsigned localhost cert (with some extra SAN values) did not, until i added it to Local Computer/Trusted Root CA.
It was already added to Current User/Trusted Root CA and Local Computer/Trusted People, but that was not enough.